# LoadError: cannot load such file -- sass-listen

Tags: sass, gemfile

I've got an html + js project I use sass with. Works great as long as I don't want to use `--watch` mode. After running:
 `sass --watch main.scss:main.css`
the error is:

```
sass --watch main.scss:main.css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sass-listen
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I have a simple Gemfile with: `gem 'listen', '~> 2.4.1'` and after running `bundle update` I got in my output:

```
Fetching listen 2.4.1
Installing listen 2.4.1
Bundle updated!
```

but still the result is the same.

Could you please help me to fix it? I'm working in WebStorm with LiveEdit plugin in js debugging mode if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

The wrong gem has been added. It needs to be `gem 'sass-listen', '~> 4.0'`. After adding that to Gemfile and running the `bundle update` everything works fine.